# Fails to push to Heroku: Sprockets::FileNotFound: could not find application.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sprockets

I used to be able to push to Heroku without problems. After making some changes, which seem unrelated to my problem, it fails to push to Heroku. On `git push heroku` I get the error:

```
...
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sprockets::FileNotFound: could not find file: /tmp/build_c657fd7***e8c75a3/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
remote:        /tmp/build_790d1e***cab4395/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:103:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_790d1***ab4395/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
...
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:  !     Push rejected to ***.
```

`application.css` does exist in my development environment and includes:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require universal
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker3
 *= require menu_header
 *= require table
 *= require wice_grid
 *= require_tree .
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing the problems and what to do about it? If I can resolve it through resetting something, then that's an option since the application isn't live yet so there's no risk of losing data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted Heroku and they described it as a slug cache issue. Clearing the cache using [purge_cache](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo#purge_cache) solved it.

Comment: That's it! Thank you

Comment: I've also seen this as a Spring issue. You can set `heroku config:set DISABLE_SPRING=1` to disable spring on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

According to researches there may be some options: 
1) Just set config.serve_static_assets to true 
2) make a rake assets:precompile before pushing , also see if you got any errors
3) .git file corrupted in git directory

Comment: Thanks Joao. 1) Dropping the entire asset pipeline is not something I want to do; 2) since I never needed to precompile I don't think that's it; 3) do you have a reference on that? then I can perhaps find out how to figure out whether that is indeed the cause and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I know that question was asked regarding Heroku but I stumbled upon the same issue on EngineYard and found a solution as well. Since I still have a low rep and I am unable to add this as a comment I am posting this as an answer although for a slightly different question...

Firstly make sure your assets are not being compiled at all (because this is where error occurs). 
Simply add those two lines to /config/ey.yml

```
precompile_assets: false
precompile_unchanged_assets: false
```

Then deploy your code with rake task: `rake tmp:cache:clear` (clears tmp/cache) or `rake tmp:clear` (clears all cache and sockets files)